# Spring boot - adding a filter

Tags: filter, spring-boot

I am wondering how I can add a filter in spring boot if the java class is only available in the app container ie it is not available at compile time.

FilterRegistrationBean can only add a Filter class and not a String of a class name that will get instantiated at run time.

Is this possible? I think I might have to add a web.xml to my project but I would prefer not to at the minute.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Filter has a no-args constructor this should work.

```
try { 
    Class c   = Class.forName("com.runtimeFilter"); 
    Filter filter = (Filter)c.newInstance();
    //register filter with bean
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

If it has a constructor with args you need to use the getConstructor() method on Class.